# Asterisk PRI Dialer Issue

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I am an experienced PHP Programmer but newbie with Asterisk. I have completed my business application which creates a list of numbers which are to be called. The system to call on SoftPhone is working perfect, but since I do not have any exposure to PRI Dialing I am not sure what needs to be done.

I am aware of libpri module but how to use is still a mystery. I tried looking into zaptel but I do not think its performing what I need. I may be wrong with this, but too much of reading on internet has not helped me at all.

I have had a discussion with few consultants and they mentioned that they have a PRI Dialer and its licenced. I cannot use that software as I need something of mine so that I can sell it further.

I need some guidance to make such PRI Dialer.

Regards,

Nitin

Comment: If you are interested to provide auto dialer and broadcasting services to your client then you may like to read [How to start your SaaS service with Auto dialer and broadcasting services](https://www.ictbroadcast.com/how-become-internet-telephony-service-provider-itsp-using-ictbroadcast-sp-edition).

Answer (score 0):

You need to interface to asterisk using the [Asterisk Manager Interface](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API) (AMI). There is a php class for doing so, called php-astmanager.php. The most up-to-date and stress tested version is distributed as a part of [FreePBX](http://www.freepbx.org/v2/svn/freepbx/branches/2.10/amp_conf/htdocs/admin/libraries/php-asmanager.php). The pri stuff is totally unrelated to what you are trying to do.

If you are using FreePBX, there is also a commercial module that dose Brodcast Dialing, available from Schmoozecom.com, here: http://freepbxdistro.org/products

Comment: What I am looking to achieve is to call up the phones and mobiles and play a particular message to them. Kind of campaign. So I need to configure PRI.

Comment: You obviously need to configure your pri card, as well as have asterisk set up. My point was that a "PRI Dialer" is akin to saying a "CIOS COmputer". Of course your computer has a bios, but that isn't what quantifies it.

Considering the scope of configuring a PRI card, you should separate your question in to two: the hardwar/pri side and the development/software side.

P.s. you don't need a pri car per se - you can enjoy the benefits of asterisk with a sip provider - cheaper and easier to set up!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the PRI set up properly in Asterisk -- meaning you are able to make and receive calls on the PRI through Asterisk, dialing through the PRI is no different than calling through SIP or any other mechanism.  As Mbrevda said, the PRI is irrelevant and there is no need for any kind of PRI dialer or anything like that.  Asterisk can handle this easily with the proper hardware (i.e. Digium or Rhino card).

Word to the wise -- ALWAYS invest in hardware-based echo cancellation.  It adds to the price of your PRI card but it is worth it 100 times over.

You can generate your calls in several ways.  This site http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+auto-dial+out has a good overview of how to create calls.  If you are looking to control this from PHP you may find using the .call file the easiest.